# Oval Flutter StrokeCap shape other than square and round for lines

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to obtain an oval line stroke cap in Flutter.

I am unsure if this is possible, the implementation is the following:

http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/flutter.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/doc/flutter/dart-ui/StrokeCap-class.html

It has a 'values' constant. How is this shape implemented?
http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/flutter.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/doc/flutter/dart-ui/Paint/strokeCap.html

I am trying to change the extended LinearPercentageIndicator widget.
https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator

Is it possible to create an oval ended line that looks like the following purple one?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOlzz.png

Comment: you have to use `Canvas.drawPath` in your case - most likely [here](https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter_percent_indicator/blob/master/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart#L272)

Comment: I have tried changing the following:
`var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0.0, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 100 / 2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, _paintBackground);
`
This particular code seems to have effect on the background of the linear indicator not the line colored itself.
[example output](https://i.imgur.com/Lgs3ilG.jpg)

Comment: you have to use a path with a round right edge - see for example `Path#arcToPoint` method